# How can i pass iterator of one map function to another function as argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have 2 map function in my file. I want the iterator variable of the second map function to be passed as an argument of another function on every button click. Fairly new to react so do not know what should i do to make it correct

```
return (    
<Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
        <EnhancedTableHead />

        <TableBody>
          {dataList.map((item, item_idx) => {

return (
                <TableRow
                  hover
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  key={item.id}
                >
                  <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell  padding="none">
                      {item.dataName}--{item.datatId}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell padding="none"  ><SwitchButton/></TableCell>
                  <TableCell    >


{
  this.state.user.map((ab, ab_idx) =>
  <li className = "display">

{isSwitchOn === false ?  <input  type = 'search' placeholder = "id"  id="name" name = "name"  onChange={(e) => this.handleidChange(e,ab_idx)}/>: " All"}
{isSwitchOn === false ? <a href="javascript:void(0)" className = "removeIcon" style={{display:(this.state.user.length > 1 )? "inline" : "none"}} onClick={() => {this.removeItem(this.state,ab_idx)}}   >Remove</a> : "" }

</li>
     )}


</TableCell>
                  <TableCell  padding="none">
                   <Button className="user-edit-btn" style={{display:(isSwitchOn === false) ? "block" : "none", textTransform: 'capitalize',}}  variant="contained" onClick={() => {this.insertTextBox(item)}}  >
                  Add User
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );

            })}

          {(
            <TableRow style={{ height: 49 }}>
              <TableCell colSpan={6} />
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
)
```

I want "ab" to be passed as an argument of the function insertTextBox(item) whenever I click on ADD USER Button. While doing that gives me an error "Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.
Did you want Fragment??"

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `handleidChange` in  your constructor like this:

`this.handleidChange = this.handleidChange.bind(this)`

Then your handler should be like this:

```
handleidChange(ab_idx, e){
   //do smth
}
```

Then pass the handler this way:

```
<input  type = 'search' placeholder = "id"  id="name" name = "name"  
onChange={this.handleidChange.bind(this, ab_idx)}/>`
```

Comment: I understand that but I want "ab" which is iterator variable of the second map function to be passed in insertTextBox() function.  insertBox function will be called on click of ADD USER button.

Comment: I apologize for my carelessness. Maybe pass function this way `onClick={() => this.insertTextBox(item)}` and why are you pass `item`, if you need to pass `ab`

Comment: That is just a placeholder for now as i do not how to pass "ab".  that is my question is actually. I am not able to pass "ab"